# chaning one CSS property and efficiency

Tags: css, performance, processing-efficiency

So this is the situation:
I'm creating a webpage with 8 tab/pull out panels (4 on the left & 4 on the right). When you click on the panel, the panel expands.
All the panels are styled the same in CSS. However, my CSS is very lengthy, because I'm duplicating the same group of properties over and over for each of the panels. The only variable that changes is the position of the panel.

My question is:
Is there are more efficient and cleaner way to code this?
--Also, I read somewhere that you can change a specific css style using jquery, but that it is less efficient.

(I've just started diving into HTML, CSS, and JS, so my understanding of everything is still vague and the terminology I'm using might be off...)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single class for all of the css styles that are being duplicated:

```
.tab-style{
   ... // whatever your duplicate styles are
}
```

Apply that class to each of your tabs.  Then create a separate classes with the different styling that go for each panel.

```
.tab1-style{
   ... // position styling for tab 1
}
.tab2-style{
   ... // position styling for tab 2
}
etc...
```

Then apply the different classes to each of the tabs.

**Example**

```
<li class='tab-style tab1-style'>....</li>
<li class='tab-style tab2-style'>....</li>
```

And so on.  This way you are only writing the shared css style one time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a common classe to add the common properties then use unique classes to change the position.

E.g.

```
.panel {
  // common styles here to apply to all panels
}

.panel.one {
  // panel one styles here
}

.panel.two {
  // panel two styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parent element and apply the common styles for the child. After that create your own style for each panel and apply it separately.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="commonstyle">
   <li class="first">First</li>
   <li class="second">Second</li>
   <li class="third">Third</li> 
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 .commonstyle li
 {
  /* All common properties */
 }  
 .first{/* First child property*/}
 .second{/* Second child property*/} 
 .third{/* Third child property*/}
```